# Concave function classification

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

A production function for a firm is defined by

$ P(x ,y ,z) = x^{\frac{1}{2}}ln y - z^{2} $

Find the set of values of y for which P(x,y,z) is a strictly concave function

$\Delta p = ( \frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{-1}{2}} lny , x^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{y}  , -2z)$
I know that a function is strictly concave when its Hessian matrix is negative definite.

I have computed the Hessian matrix 
$$H (x,y,z)= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1}{4}x^{\frac{-3}{2}} lny &  \frac{1}{2} x^{\frac{-1}{2}} \frac{1}{y} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{y} & -x^{-\frac{1}{2}}  & 0  \\ 0 &  0 &  -2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

A negative definite Hessian is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for strict concavity. But here this will do. I assume $x,y,z \ge 0$ because we are dealing with a production function.

The Hessian is negative definite if its leading principal minors alternate in sign. The correct Hessian for your function (yours had a typo in $h_{22}$) is 
$$H (x,y,z)= \begin{pmatrix} -\dfrac{x^{-3/2}\ln y}{4} &  \dfrac{x^{-1/2}}{2y} & 0 \\ \dfrac{x^{-1/2}}{2y} & - \dfrac{x^{1/2}}{y^2} & 0  \\ 0 &  0 &  -2 \end{pmatrix} $$

The first leading principal minor
$$-\frac{x^{-3/2}\ln y}{4} < 0$$
implies $x>0$ and $y>1$. The second leading principal minor
$$\dfrac{x^{-1}}{4y^2} \left(\ln y - 1\right) >0$$
implies $y > e$. Finally, the third leading principal minor being strictly negative adds no further restrictions.

Combining the above, we get $x>0$ and $y>e$.